# Hive auth. (user name contains @) issue

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying out Hive sql based authorization now, It works great.
But when I connect for example with beeline to hs2:

!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 alice@something.com password

and try to drop a table:
Permission denied: Principal [name=alice, type=USER] does not have following privileges for operation....

The hive see I'm "alice" instead of "alice@something.com". So I can not grant properly the users.

I appreacite any help about it, how I can prevent to cut the @something.com part.

thank you

Comment: Use a `\ ` to escape the `@` ?

Comment: same problem, but thank you

!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 alice\@something.com password
Principal [name=alice\, type=USER]